# What is the value of a pointer variable without the de-reference symbol?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have searched all over for an explanation to the following code, and I can't find it anywhere. I know the output is 5, but can someone explain to me why it's 5? *b is equal to 2 after the 2nd to last line is evaluated, (I know why that is), but I don't know why b[3] equals 5. I just need the last line explained.

```
int* a = new int[10];

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     a[i] = i;

int* b = &a[2];

cout << b[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

After the assignment to `b`, it now points to the third element in the `a` array (i.e., the value "1").

The expression `b[3]` is equivalent to `*(b+3)` which means get the value which is *three positions after b* (this is essentially pointer arithmetic - `b+3` is a pointer that is 3 positions after `b`.  In this case 3 integers after `b`). So since b points to `a[2]`, adding 3 makes it point to `a[2+3]` or `a[5]` which equals 5 (since the first loop makes `a[i]==i`).

Comment: Correct. Fixed.

Comment: If you run the code, the output is 5. This was a question on a past exam I took, and 5 is correct, but I can't figure out why.

Comment: My bad! The question was what is the output of b[3]. I had the code wrong in the original post. I understand the answer. Thanks, All!

Comment: This answer is correct, except that the OP subsequently edited the question.  Edit this to describe the effects of accessing `b[3]` rather than `b[2]`, and it will be correct in light of the OP's edits.

Answer (score 0):

[cppreference: operator_member_access - Built-in_subscript_operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator)

> The built-in subscript expression `E1[E2]` is exactly identical to the expression `*(E1 + E2)` except evaluation order (since C++17), that is, the pointer operand (which may be a result of array-to-pointer conversion, and which must point to an element of some array or one past the end) is adjusted to point to another element of the same array, following the rules of pointer arithmetics, and is then dereferenced.